# How do i use a gui i build together with functions from somewhere else?

Tags: java, swing

Hello im new here i am making a small tictactoe game where i have made a gui as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame frame1 =new Frame("TickTacToe");
    frame1.setLayout(null);
    frame1.setBounds(250,150,500,500);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    final Button button11 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button12 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button13 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button21 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button22 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button23 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button31 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button32 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);

    final Button button33 = new Button("");
    button11.addActionListener(null);


    button11.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 70);
    button12.setBounds(100, 200, 80, 70);
    button13.setBounds(100, 300, 80, 70);
    button21.setBounds(200, 100, 80, 70);
    button22.setBounds(200, 200, 80, 70);
    button23.setBounds(200, 300, 80, 70);
    button31.setBounds(300, 100, 80, 70);
    button32.setBounds(300, 200, 80, 70);
    button33.setBounds(300, 300, 80, 70);

    frame1.add(button11); 
    frame1.add(button12); 
    frame1.add(button13); 
    frame1.add(button21); 
    frame1.add(button22); 
    frame1.add(button23); 
    frame1.add(button31); 
    frame1.add(button32);
    frame1.add(button33); 
}
```

I want to add action listeners to the buttons but not in this void ideall even a different class so i can create a way to run a loop of functions such as a player turn changer where if it is turn one it will set button text to x and o if it is the otheI know more orless the code i would need to use but i cant figure out a way to use the gui from anzwhere else than its own void. I dont quite know what im searching for so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a question. You need to know how to handle classes and functions in java. How to use an (MVC pattern) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller. Please read some java swing tutorials to find your way around

Comment: so the void Main here is inside class Gui i tried to use it some what like this :
public class Main {
 
 private Main(String[] args){
  Gui g = new Gui;
  Gameloop gl = new Gameloop;
  
  
 }

}
Gameloop is where i have the functions could i put them together somehow like this?
Is this going the right direction?

Comment: Either use an array for your buttons (if that applies) or name them better than button31, etc!

Comment: @user1489906 : I made this a long long time back, though don't know how much will it help, since as my knowledge grew with Java, I realized, many a things are really not done in the way I thought I must. But [here](https://gagandeepbali.uk.to/svn/myrepository/), this code of the said game might can give you some idea. Username : guest Password : guest

Comment: @nice cow Thanks for the link to the project it will be helpful.

Comment: @Lee Taylor The idea behind the bottons are that the button names are that thez represnt an array i never thought about the idea of a button array or how that woud work but ill look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this program structure is pretty bad. From the looks of it I can tell you came from a procedural programming language like C or Basic or something of the sort. Java is all about Object Oriented architecture. Java can run procedurally but it was not meant to be. First thing that I would start with is get out of main(). Here is a good way to do that:

```
public class TicTacToe
{
    public TicTacToe()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```

TicTacToe might seem simple but it has a lot of things going on at once, people are clicking buttons so you need ActionListeners, you need to update the UI of the screen after every move, you need to check to make sure each move is valid, you need to check for a win after every move and much much more. This is almost impossible to do inside of main.

It's generally a bad idea to add any sort of Component straight into a JFrame. Its better to put a JPanel inside of a JFrame and then add the components to the JPanel.

Try making a class structure for your game. Here is what I would do:

```
TicTacToe.class --> Checks rules, checks for wins and starts and stops game
Player.class (implements ActionListener) --> Listens for each Player's input
Board.class (extends JPanel) --> this will display the components for the game
Computer.class (extends Player) --> if you wanted to create an AI this is where you would do so
```

If I was you I would read a book about Java Game Development or take a class. If you want to get good at Java that is a good place to start. Your missing a lot of crucial knowledge that you need to do even a simple task such as make a TicTacToe game.

Comment: Thank You, You are right that that i started with basic. I am starting programming for my first year of IB in school next year was hoping to get a head start, im hoping this is the right waz to do it :)